# css layout of internal div

Tags: css

The pagination id div (with red doted border and bottom of the black border div) is not going at top inner corner of black border div

[`jsfiddle.net/GMLGn/8/`](http://jsfiddle.net/GMLGn/8/)

The code is too long to post here (stack chars limit) and its not feasible to give partial code in current scenario.

Comment: jsfiddle is easy to use. just ctrl+f and get to pagination . I included all the page because some other div or style might be effecting the questioned one

Comment: I had some answers in waiting. check the acceptance now

Comment: and if got the answer to my valid question. so it can be answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add these position to the classes `.galary` and `.pagation`

```
.galary{
position:relative;
}
```

do this if you want to make sure pagination does not go outside of the galary element

```
.pagination{
  position:absolute;     
}
```

this will allow you to move the pagination element whereever you want with the top and left settings

Comment: position is not declared, isnt it relative by default? (which looks contrary as your answer solved the problem)

Comment: @Masood - I believe that static is default

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you're asking for (though it is hard to be sure)

Set the position: absolute and adjust the top and left properties accordingly;

This is what I put in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcurran/zwQjD/):

```
.gallery .pagination{
border: medium dotted #930;
left: 664px;
top: 187px;
width: 150px;
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: looks ok in fiddle but in browser it has made the pagination relative to the page (with absoloute positioning) If  resize page, pagination gets out of the div